# How set a people field with JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, people-picker, spservices

With `SPServices` I'm getting information from a list A that information contains in one of its columns a people field.

In the form B I need to copy that person coming from the list A in one of the columns that B has that is a people field too.

How could I do that?
The format of the information I'm getting form `SPServices` looks like:

```
4#;Coello Yngrid
```

Can I set a people field with that information? Cleaning that field I can get the name of the person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used the following javascript to set people pickers on new/edit forms in SP2013:

First you need to get the loginName for the user, you could extract the ID from the value you got and use it to get the loginName through a REST query:

```
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccess,
  error : onError});
```

Using the property LoginName returned by the REST query the people picker can be set using the following code (assuming jQuery is available):

```
var loginName = "i:0#.w|contoso\\johannes"; // Assume this is the returned value from the rest query 
var form = jQuery("table[class='ms-formtable']"); // get the form element
var userField = form.find("input[id$='ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput']").get(0) // find the people picker element, assuming you dont have multiple people pickers on the form 
var peoplepicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.PickerObjectFromSubElement(userField) // Use SPClientPeoplePicker to get the actual picker object
peoplepicker.AddUserKeys(loginName); // finally set the loginName as the people picker value, this also triggers a validation.
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Just a comment: If you have multiple people picker elements you can find your people picker using the Title in your element input[id$='ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput']

Comment: This is the cleanest and simplest solution I've seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link

http://sympmarc.com/2012/04/22/working-with-sharepoint-people-pickers-with-jquery-a-new-function-called-findpeoplepicker/

And use following code to set picker value

```
siteContactPeoplePicker = $().findPeoplePicker({
    peoplePickerDisplayName: "Site Contact",
    valueToSet: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser()
});
```

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me into the right direction. The code in the post didn't work for me though

Comment: @yngrdyn Ok. on a side note in 2013 we Have REST API. So you don't need `SPServices`. I would suggest you follow in that line.